# Как моделировать нажатие на клавиатуру в windows?

Tags: windows, bat

Мне нужно написать `.bat` файлик, в котором будет запускаться определенная последовательность нажатий на клавиатуру раз в день. Как это сделать? (Можно и не `.bat` файл. Любой способ, которым можно это сделать.)

Нужны сочетания клавиш: `alt+d`, `enter`, стрелочка вниз.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно и не .bat файл. Любой способ, которым можно это сделать.

VBS, например... у объекта WScript.Shell есть метод [Sendkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Пример на powershell

```
//Создаем WScript.Shell
$myshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell 
$myshell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

в данном примере отсылаем команду на нажатие кнопки Enter, посмотреть все возможные варианты можно тут [SendKeys Method/microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Вы хотите Сделать что то ? (Enter - да, любая клавиша - нет)
powershell.exe -Command "$key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown').Character; if ([int]$key -eq 13) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }"

REM Проверка нажатой клавиши
if not %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    echo Вы не нажали на Enter.
    TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
    exit /b
)
```